# iPhone Develpment Certificate Expired Earlier than the Expiry Date

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

This is a very strange situation. I wonder if anyone has come across it before. On the apple developer portal it shows that there are 10 days for the development certificate to expire, but today the certificate in my keychain has expired. So how come the certificate got expired 10 days before the actual date. I renewed my developer license 2 days back, does that have anything to do with this?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you ask apple about this?

Comment: I had to revoke the certificate and its working fine. Didn't have that much of time